# setting expiration time to django password reset token

Tags: python, django, django-users

I am using the inbuilt password reset functionality of Django which emails the user the password reset link. Is there an option in Django to set an expiration time to the link suppose 6 hours after which the link become invalid and user will have to request again for password recovery.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you're using Django's built-in password reset functionality, you can use the setting `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS`.

Example: if a user uses a password reset link that was generated 2 days ago and you have `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS=1` in your project's settings, the link will be invalid and the user cannot continue.

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout-days

Answer (score 19):

Django includes functionality to expire the token in less than 1 day in Django **3.1** or newer. Use the setting `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT` which takes number of seconds after which token will expire.

```py
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT = 259200 # 3 days, in seconds
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout

Comment: Actually, by default, it expires after [3 days](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout)